# Checkstyle or PMD rule for checking if methods in interface have comments

Tags: java, checkstyle, pmd

How can I write a rule for checking if methods in a interface have comments and which would be better to do so, checkstyle or PMD?

Comment: Do you want to write your own rule, or do you just want to configure it?

Comment: Either would work, I haven't all of the tutorials I have read on making PMD rules don't cover comments.

Comment: I figured it out. Checkstyle has a built in method of checking only interface classes by using the interface token. Here is the code that it generated. Its not possible to post code blocks in comments so here it is inline:   `<module name="Checker">    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>    <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="scope" value="package"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="INTERFACE_DEF"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
`